# How to fix excel printing wrong axis label?

Tags: excel

I want the x label to be datetime just like colum 1, but when i plot the values they turn into number. Dose anyone know why this happens and how i can fix it? Here is a screenshot of the
[image: Excel] sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the format of the values using following steps:

- Click the X axis
- Right click on it and select **Formal Axis**
- Select axis option (the icon looks like bar chart) in the right pane
- Select Numbers **->** Category **->** Choose the `Date` or `custom` and do the changes

Comment: I tried all of the categories but non of then gave a label that was like or similar to what is in colum 1